# no Theme Selector on SQL Developer 17.3

Tags: ide, sqldeveloper

I have been trying to change the theme of SQL Developer, and I am unable to find the theme selector under Environment in the preferences.

has it been removed?

[image: where is it?]
Normally this is where it would be located.

Comment: I have been trying to get my theme to work for at least an hour.  pretty sure I have typed theme into that search.

Comment: when you type theme into it, it actually only shows the environment option.

Comment: `Look and Feel` has always been there from what I have seen in screen shots. --> https://amikhaylin.com/2013/03/13/dark-theme-for-oracle-jdevelopersql-developer/

Comment: @Ramhound that post is from a previous version of SQLDeveloper **7 YEARS AGO**  not applicable here.  I did see that post, but it doesn't help me

Comment: I have no idea if the theme you are attempting to use is compatible with 17.3, my screenshot was 17.4 (since I never use out of date software), the information I found indicate this change happened over 3 years ago.  Your own article is from 6 years ago, so I doubt that theme, even supports 17.3 but your question has nothing to do with that (potential problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has it been removed?

It was just renamed

[image]

Comment: [This change happened 3 years ago](https://github.com/ozmoroz/ozbsidian-sqldeveloper)

Comment: I was able to find this setting, but it is different from Theme, which affects a lot more than just the code editing windows.

Comment: Then Oracle has changed how themes worked within SQL Developer.  Because "twilight" is clearly a "Theme".  It's considered a theme in nearly every program I have every worked with.

Comment: when I search for Theme, Environment still shows up.  did it show up for you on the Environment tab?

Comment: @Malachi - Yes I did

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the "Code Editor" then drill down to "PL/SQL Syntax Colors", you can change the color of the background and the font colors for the various "Styles"...

[SQL Developer Theme change/modify/save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noqII.png)